# Is it possible to use Rtable (FlexTable) to generate a pdf table in RMarkdown

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, flextable, reporters

I'm creating some RMarkdown reports and want to be able to extensively format a table. I've tried working with kable and pander but they don't give me enough functionality (for example to use colors for rows).

I ran across the Rtable package (that goes along with the FlexTable object of the Reporters package) which allows significant customization. The only problem is that I can so far only get my table to show up when I knit to html, when I knit to pdf (what I need) I just get an unformatted list of text instead of my table.

here's what my code looks like (summaryterms is a dataframe)

```
setZebraStyle(FlexTable(summaryterms[c(5,1:3,9:11,14)]),odd = "#DDDDDD", even    = "#FFFFFF" )
```

Is there anyway to use the FlexTable object with a pdf report?

Thank you so much for the help

Also, I'm open to any and all other solutions to format tables in rmarkdown, I'm not married to using flextable.

Comment: Have you had any success yet? I am very curious. Thanks!

Comment: you can use the knit_print function, i.e. knit_print(flex_table)

Comment: Did it really turn out to be so simple? Thanks!